# How to persist my console setfont choice?

Tags: linux, console, embedded-linux

I have a BeagleBone Black, with a 4.3" LCD Cape. It's running the up-to-date angstrom distribution. I'm running with Gnome/X disabled, so I just have a simple text console on my display at the moment. But the initial font it chooses is nearly unreadable.

So I installed the `kbd` and `kdb-console` packages so that I could use something like `setfront drdos8x16` to fix my font. It works great.

But each time I reboot the device, I have to redo that. Is there a way to make it so that it chooses that larger drdos8x16 font by default at startup?

Comment: Do I need to word my question differently to avoid the close votes?

Comment: Can't you add the setfont command with the font file to a startup script?

Comment: Yes, I could I guess. Didn't even occur to me. This isn't the kind of thing I would see putting in inittab (but maybe I should??). And putting in a init script to do it seems even bigger overkill, but maybe I'm just off base?